# Problems with url rewrite of query string

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite urls like http://www.url.com/blog/?p=123 to http://www.url.com/#blog/123. I've read up on things and found that you can only parse the query string in the RewriteCond so I tried something like:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /#blog/%0 [NE,R]
```

When I try this the urls end up being rewritten to:

> http://www.url.com/#blog/p=213?p=213

Any ideas how to do this properly? Also, is there a way to add an additional RewriteCond that checks that the `REQUEST_URI` contains blog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by removing the query string entirely:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /#blog/%1? [NE,R]
```

This should give you:

```
http://www.url.com/#blog/213
```

If you want to check if the URL contains the term "blog" then simply check:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/blog/.*
```

It is important to note that you will not be able to check for "blog" in links like `http://www.url.com/#blog` because, as noted by Patrick, everything after the `#` is not sent to the server.

See the [Apache wiki on mod_rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) for more information.

Comment: Is there anyway to get rid of the p= in the rewritten url? I need http://www.url.com/#blog/213 not http://www.url.com/#blog/p=213.

Comment: @blcArmadillo -- sorry, that was a typo -- the rewrite rule I gave you should give you url.com/#blog/213.

Comment: I too would think that this would work however for some reason it still puts p= in the rewritten url... odd. Any ideas?

Comment: Aha I just realized that the %0 in the RewriteRule should be changed to %1.

Comment: *Smacks head* -- Should have realized that.  I have updated my answer as well -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That may not work because browsers do not send the fragment of the url after the hash (#) with the request, so any request for http://www.url.com/#blog/p=213?p=213 will be a request for http://www.url.com/

The hash fragment is supposed to be used for anchor tags on pages, and is never sent to the server.

Comment: The request the user is sending is http://www.url.com/blog/?p=123. But with the current rewrite rules I have in place the request url is being rewritten to http://www.url.com/#blog/p=213?p=213 when I want it to be rewritten to http://www.url.com/#blog/213.

Comment: Don't use the hash in the rewrite rule for the above reasons. To get it working without the hash, use something like this: `RewriteRule ^/blog/([0-9]+)$ blog/$1 [R=301]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/?$ /#blog/%1? [NC,NE,L,R]
```

With above a URL of `http://localhost/blog/?p=1234` will become `http://localhost/#blog/1234`