# Htaccess redirect long urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've got problem with redirecting old google maps urls to new one. I got new links (after component update), but i want make old ones work.

this is old one

```
domain.com/index.php?option=com_xmap&sitemap=1&view=xml
```

this is new one

```
domain.com/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml&tmpl=component&id=1
```

Please, help me redirect this :)

Comment: If the query parameters can appear in a random order, you'll need to use a solution similar to what [Jon Lin suggested for my question a while back](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17793597/2209007). If the parameters in the query appear in the same order every time, use `RewriteCond` with `%{QUERY_STRING}` like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5824767/problems-with-url-rewrite-of-query-string).

Comment: I tried many combinations, but i only got 500 error :/ I figured out, that soulution is to add only "id=1" on the end of new url, to work, 

second solution is rewrite "sitemap" to "id"  - bot how do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following redirect would work. It redirects when there is no `id=` in the query string, and appends `id=somenumber` to the query string where `somenumber` is the number behind sitemap.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*&|)id=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*&|)sitemap=([0-9]+)(&.*|)$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?id=%2 [QSA,R,L]
```

A quick rundown of what I used here. `%{QUERY_STRING}` is a variable, just as `%{REQUEST_URI}`. A `!` before a regex will negate that regex (ala 'doesn't contain'). `%2` is replaced with the second capturing group of the last `RewriteCond`. In this case it will get replaced by whatever is captured by `([0-9]+)`. The flags are `QSA` (query string append), `R` (redirect, default is temporary redirect) and `L` (if this rule matches, stop rewriting; this doesn't affect the new request that is made). The documentation can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).